# Machines making machines

Tags: star-wars

> "Oh my goodness, shut me down! Machines making machines - how perverse!"
>   - C-3PO, *Star Wars Episode II:  Attack of the Clones*

I think this exclamation of 3PO's is merely a remark to the fact that he was actually built by a sentient.

But how about the rest? Are the majority of machines and devices in the galaxy built by labor or robotics? Xi Char, Huppla Pasa Tisc, Techno Union, SoroSuub, CEC, KDY, Sienar...

What is the "norm"? Sentient labor or machines making machines?

Comment: C3P0 probably isn't an expert in manufacturing.

Comment: Yeah, he's only good for communicating with the Falcon. And doomsday announcements.

Comment: Unless there is a huge underpayed/slave labor planet somewhere mass manuacturing robots in secret, 99% or more are created by other machines, no diferent from our universe today. Maybe a few school projecs or experimental prototpes created by enineering savants(Anakin).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with the statement is WHO says it. C3PO. He is more or less a special case as his earliest memory is being built together by a human being (Anakin). Additionally he has a seemingly low oppinion for many types of robots (especially in the films 4-6 where he makes quite a few jabs at R2 despite them being friends which indicate that he sees astromech droids as inferior to protocol droids).

If we take his history into account the comment of his sounds less strange. For example if you went into a facility where humans were manufactored by machines wouldn't you say the same thing? ("Machines making humans- how perverse!") For us this would be going completely against all that we know and believe. And for him he only knows that humans (anakin) build droids.

That is the only reason I can think of there which relates to things shown and mentioned on screen (the other possibility that normally labor forces produce droids is.....unrealistical if we think about how many droids are there)